# Remove unused Font Awesome icons

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I uploaded the files to my server but I'm only using 5 icons in my site.

How can I delete the Font Awesome icons that I will never use? Like the useful and beautiful Stethoscope.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stethoscope/

Thank you

Comment: See fontforge intructions and script here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434789/5426839

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like you copied the entire font-awesome directory into your project, and this isn't the result you are looking for. If you only want 5 of the Font Awesome icons in your project, and not have the balance of icons available for future use, take a look at [Fontello](http://fontello.com/).

Fontello is an icon fonts generator which allows you to pick and choose only the icon fonts you want for your project.

Here's a link to Fontello on GitHub, with information on how to use it: 
https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/Help

Answer (score 3):

Another option you have if you only need a few icons, it's [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) where you can choose the icons that are going to be loaded only including the ones from Font-Awesome.

Otherwise, check [this blog](https://blog.webjeda.com/optimize-fontawesome/) that explains how to reduce font-awesome size.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using javascript module imports try:

`import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCoffee' // <-- note the extra faCoffee there`