# How can I purge unused fontawesome icons?

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm using Wordpress and FontAwesome is loaded from local server(not CDN.)

I would like to purge unused FA because of heavy file size(280KB total).

Can I use this git to purge unused FA on my Wordpress?

https://github.com/dhardtke/font-awesome-minify-plugin

I would like to minify files, font-awesome.min.css, fa-brands-400.woff2, fa-light-300.woff2, fa-regular-400.woff2, fa-solid-900.woff2

I need your help.

Thank you. :)

Comment: 280KB is considered "heavy file size"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove unused Font Awesome icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048422/remove-unused-font-awesome-icons)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think I only use 20KB now, so I can save 200KB :)

Comment: See fontforge intructions and script here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434789/5426839

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a few icons you may want to use [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) where you can choose the icons from **Font-Awesome** (amongst others) that are going to be loaded only.

Otherwise, you may want to check [this blog](https://blog.webjeda.com/optimize-fontawesome/) that explains how to reduce font-awesome size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I read that blog a few days ago, but I cannot chose unused fontawesome, because the theme and plugin used more than 150 FA...:(

Comment: Is there any way to use this one on my Wordpress? https://github.com/ecomfe/fontmin